# APIM Generate JsonArray to EventHub

Tags: json, azure, json.net, azure-api-management

Facing an issue with JArray to generate data

My current APIM Policy

```
<log-to-eventhub logger-id="testjayeventhub">@{return new JObject(
    new JProperty("EventTime", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()),
    new JProperty("ServiceName", context.Deployment.ServiceName),
    new JProperty("RequestId", context.RequestId),
    new JProperty("RequestIp", context.Request.IpAddress),
    new JProperty("OperationName", context.Operation.Name)
).ToString();}</log-to-eventhub>
```

The above will generate the data with the below model and send to the eventhub

```
{
  "EventTime": "...",
  "ServiceName": "yyyy",
  "RequestId": "yyyy",
  "RequestIp": "yyy",
  "OperationName": "xxx"
}
```

However, I want to change this data model like below

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "EventTime": "...",
      "ServiceName": "yyyy",
      "RequestId": "yyyy",
      "RequestIp": "yyy",
      "OperationName": "xxx"
    }
  ]
}
```

So I'm trying to change my policy but i can't able to do that. So far i have tried the below

```
JObject jobj = new JObject(
    new JProperty("EventTime", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()),
    new JProperty("ServiceName", context.Deployment.ServiceName),
    new JProperty("RequestId", context.RequestId),
    new JProperty("RequestIp", context.Request.IpAddress),
    new JProperty("OperationName", context.Operation.Name)
);

JArray a = new JArray();
a.Add(jobj);
```

But this will just add the JObject into array but not sure how the record model will get into..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, seems to work for me ...

```
var jsonString = new JObject(
    new JProperty("records", new JArray() {
        new JObject(
            new JProperty("EventTime", "yyy"),
            new JProperty("ServiceName", "yyy"),
            new JProperty("RequestId", "yyy"),
            new JProperty("RequestIp", "yyy"),
            new JProperty("OperationName", "yyy")
        )
    })
).ToString();

return jsonString;
```